# Possible to capture and re-broadcast as RTMP?

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, flash-player, rtmp, live-video

I may have a need coming up soon to capture a live video broadcast stream and re-broadcast it as an RTMP stream for playback in Flash Player.

Is this possible? I'm seeing posts online from 2005 to 2009 claiming that RTMP either isn't or is poorly supported in VLC.

I do not currently know what format the incoming video stream will be -- will update when I get that information.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flash Media Server ([which you can download for free](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/compare/)). Then follow [this help article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773cfae-7ff3.html) from Adobe. With a little action script, it should be pretty easy.

There is also a free plugin (flow player) you can download [from here](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html) that will connect to your RTMP source and output to swf.

Comment: This isn't quite the answer I was looking for, although helpful. I'm looking to rebroadcast an existing stream, not just stream a file.